# How to retrive the rows with not empty associations in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

As an example I have two tables in the DB with One2Many relations.

Consider next piece of code (types are straight from the documentation with little changes):

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
    "github.com/gofrs/uuid"
    "gorm.io/driver/mysql"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
    "gorm.io/gorm/clause"
)

type Email struct {
    ID      uuid.UUID `gorm:"primary_key;type:char(36);"`
    Address string    `gorm:"unique"`
    Uid     uuid.UUID
}

type User struct {
    ID     uuid.UUID `gorm:"primary_key;type:char(36);"`
    Name   string    `gorm:"unique"`
    Emails []Email   `gorm:"ForeignKey:Uid"`
}

func main() {
    var err error
    var db *gorm.DB
    db, err = gorm.Open(mysql.New(mysql.Config{
        DSN: "root:AsdfgH123@tcp(localhost:3306)/maindb?charset=utf8&parseTime=True&loc=Local",
    }), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = db.AutoMigrate(
        &User{},
        &Email{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    uid1, _ := uuid.NewV7()
    uid2, _ := uuid.NewV7()
    eid1, _ := uuid.NewV7()
    eid2, _ := uuid.NewV7()

    users := []User{
        {Name: "user_1", ID: uid1, Emails: []Email{{ID: eid1, Address: "user_1@example.com"}}},
        {Name: "user_2", ID: uid2, Emails: []Email{{ID: eid2, Address: "user_2@example.com"}}},
    }
    db.Clauses(clause.Insert{Modifier: "IGNORE"}).Create(&users)
    dbUsers := []User{}

    db.Preload("Emails", "address like 'user_1@%'").Find(&dbUsers)

    spew.Dump(dbUsers)
}
```

And as a result I'm getting this:

```json
([]main.User) (len=2 cap=20) {
 (main.User) {
  ID: (uuid.UUID) (len=16 cap=16) 01833180-a4f4-7663-a73e-798b110724ed,
  Name: (string) (len=6) "user_1",
  Emails: ([]main.Email) (len=1 cap=10) {
   (main.Email) {
    ID: (uuid.UUID) (len=16 cap=16) 01833180-a4f4-70e6-ad25-c5726212a97c,
    Address: (string) (len=18) "user_1@example.com",
    Uid: (uuid.UUID) (len=16 cap=16) 01833180-a4f4-7663-a73e-798b110724ed
   }
  }
 },
 (main.User) {
  ID: (uuid.UUID) (len=16 cap=16) 01833180-a4f4-738f-ad46-1c7bb36cf79c,
  Name: (string) (len=6) "user_2",
  Emails: ([]main.Email) (cap=10) {
  }
 }
}
```

I can filter the results in `dbUsers` based on the fact that `user.Emails` is not an empty list. But is it possible to do that purely with GORM? To GORM to only return the users with the email requested in `Preload`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be able to solve this using subqueries. Sorry, I cannot run it against a mysql database, so it is untested, but I guess you'll get the gist:

```golang
subQuery := db.Select("uid").Where("address like 'user_1@%'").Table("emails")

db.Where("id IN (?)", subQuery).Find(&dbUsers)
```

Comment: Thanks. This one works: db.Preload("Emails").Where("id IN (?)", subQuery).Find(&dbUsers)